# How to control an executable file (.exe) written in python with a python script?

Tags: python, windows, exe, grasshopper

So I turned a Keras based python script in to an exe program with a GUI (using tkinter) through pyinstaller. The program reads a jpeg and gives you a similarity ratio with certain architects. I programmed the exe in a manner that the gui buttons trigger the functions inside the program. Now I'm looking for a way to automate this process entirely.

I would ideally want a python script that can fire up the exe and load the image and ask the program to execute the task. What would be the way to do it? I know we can use the os module to execute an exe with py script but I cannot figure out how to control the exe with the python.

I'm open to re-programming my exe in a different manner if that's the only way but would prefer not to.

P.S: For those on here who know what Rhino and grasshopper are, the end goal here is to have python script in grasshopper run the exe and carry out the analysis.

I'm not exactly proficient in programming and therefore my entire way of going about it could be wrong.

[Screenshot of UI for reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S78I5.png)

Comment: How about via command line arguments?

Comment: You mean inside the python script?

Answer (score 0):

In the meantime, I have been resorted to using pywinauto to control the GUI and automate the process allowing me to click and type.

I would still prefer a more elegant solution to this.